# Repetition algorithm problem, Java

Tags: java

Set an algorithm that reads a undetermined number of values to m, all positive ints, one at a time. If m is even, verify how many divisors there is and write that information. If m is odd calculate and write the factored of m.

How do I do that? I'm entirely confused by that problem, I need a light on that subject.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What did you try? What didn't work? What should have worked? What didn't you understand? What did you understand?

Comment: I'm in a total blank. I first thought I could do by setting a "if statement" to the numbers, but my line of thought breaks there.

Comment: Are you sure there's no "stop" condition ? Put another way: when should the program stop ?

Comment: I don't know how to proceed with that activity. If someone could tell me at least how to proceed from a starting point I guess I could figure the rest

Comment: @user: that seems a good idea. Do that. What part is blocking your progress? Please check out our [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) which will help you write effective questions. You'll find a lot of helpful people here who are eager to answer **specific** questions. But you have to tell us what your problem is.

Comment: @nc3b I guess the odd numbers will when the M value reaches an ODD number so it goes for even. I guess

Comment: @Martinho Thank you. But I guess my problem is to figure it out this question. I was given this assignment (i just copied the question, no rewriting). Maybe the question itself is a puzzle.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have a loop which repeatedly calls a method `readAndWorkWithNumber()`.
This method

- reads a number `m` (might call another method to do this)
- checks if `m` is odd or even

  - if odd, calls `factorize(m)`.
  - if even, calls `countFactors(m)`.

The last two methods should then do what their name said, and output the result. (Alternatively, return it and output it in `readAndWorkWith`).

Comment: I'll make my best effort to understand what you just said. But I guess i've got my answer here, in your wise words (:

Comment: @user711505: If you need more details, ask more specifically. The answer was intentionally a bit vague, as I didn't want to do your complete homework.

Comment: Do I have to use the While Loop?

Comment: Any loop will do (`for`, `do`, `while`), but here in fact a simple `while(true) { ... }` seems to be fine (as long as you don't have a way of knowing when to end the program).

Comment: for exemple, I'll make an int count = m (m being the variable right? in which i'll in this exemple set as 10) and until the value 10 the "while  counter < 10 shall work the even and odd numbers.. right? IM confused.

Comment: You only need a counter if the user (or someone else) can decide how many numbers there will be.

Comment: @user711505: First focus on a simpler program, which reads *one* number, and then either outputs the number of factors or the factorization. Adding the loop later is easy.

Comment: Right, so I think i'm getting the idea here. I've figured that if I use the while loop for example, since i've set the counter = 0 and "while" is less than 10. doing it again and again until 0. but now i'm confused again. What should i do if the values between that is even and get to know how many divisors there is??

Comment: Show what you have yet (in an edit to the question), then it is easier to help.

Comment: I couldn't do it just yet. I was looking through tutorials to see if I can get a handle at this. I've found a neat video tutorial by the user "thenewboston", i'm trying to figure which variables to use yet. (this is my first year in programming)

Comment: Paulo, i'm amolst giving up. Could you please see if im goin in the right direction?